# Close angular datepicker on escape

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I'm using [angular-datepicker](https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker) in my angular App. it works perfectly fine but I'm trying to close it on escape key press but unable to do that.

I've tried [this solution](https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker/pull/96/files) but its not working for me. Is there any other way to close datepicker on escape? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

I didn't find pure angular code to do this. So I'm trying jquery. This is what I'm currently doing. I've captured `keydown` event and trying to hide calendar this way

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {

   if(event.which === 27) //escape
   {    
       $('#StartDate ~ .720kb.datepicker').hide();

   }
}
```

But its not working ...

Comment: you tried *what* solution?  you didn't post the code for a solution, you posted changes to the repository.  If you are suggesting that either that fix or some code you added to try fixing it yourself didn't work, then you should post a [mcve] for review.

Comment: I've tried many solutions but nothing worked for me. One of them is mentioned in my updated question.

Comment: the code you added there is only a snippet, it's still not a [mcve]. It is also not angular code, it's JQuery.  *where* did you add this code, *what* is responding to `event`, and *why* are you trying to use JQuery?

Comment: Angular 1.x or 2?

Comment: I looked over the datepicker docs. I'm not sure your usage comes from there (and don't see "hide", just "show[true-false]". Take a look:

.controller('TestController', ['$scope', '$interval', function TestController($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.visibility = true;

    $interval(function setInterval() {
      //toggling manually everytime
      $scope.visibility = !$scope.visibility;
    }, 3500);
  }]);
  <datepicker ng-controller="TestController" datepicker-show="{{visibility}}">
      <input ng-model="date3" type="text" class="angular-datepicker-input"/>
    </datepicker>

Comment: @TimConsolazio angular 1

Comment: @Claies m trying jqeury because am unable to find any solution in angular. I'm newbie in angular

Comment: the "solution" that you said you tried and posted a link to was definitely angular (it used `$scope`), but then you posted a code snippet suggesting it was what you tried that didn't work, but the code you posted is nothing like what was in the link.  You still haven't posted any additional code for anyone to work from.

Comment: @Claies solution in link was about changes in datepicker directive that i did the same as mentioned but didn't work for me. then i tried simple jquery keydown event capture to hide it manually but i also didn't work

Comment: ok, then post a ***complete*** example?  I've asked in every comment, but you haven't yet done so, or even mentioned why you can't show something more complete.

Answer (score 1):

I looked over the datepicker docs. I'm not sure your usage comes from there (I don't see "hide", just "show[true-false]". Take a look:

```
.controller('TestController', ['$scope', '$interval', function TestController($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.visibility = true;

    $interval(function setInterval() {
      //toggling manually everytime
      $scope.visibility = !$scope.visibility;
    }, 3500);
  }]);
  <datepicker ng-controller="TestController" datepicker-show="{{visibility}}">
      <input ng-model="date3" type="text" class="angular-datepicker-input"/>
    </datepicker>
```

Comment: yeah I've read them again and trying to do it with datepicker-show.. Thank you for giving me hint